# How can I install PEAR::Mail for TYPO3 without pear or phar?

Tags: php, pear, typo3, pecl, phar

In order to use the TYPO3 extension 'Direct Mail' with an external SMTP server, I need to install PEAR::Mail (http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download/1.2.0).

At least, that is what the text in the Direct Mail configuration tells me:

> Enable Sending through SMTP [SmtpEnabled]
>       Send all emails not through sendmail but through an external SMTP
>   account (requires PEAR::Mail to be installed on the system)

*I have neither pear nor phar available.*

**How do I install the package after downloading it manually?**

Comment: I managed to get PEAR to my avail and simply installed PEAR::Mail from the ports DB of my OS. However, I am leaving this open, as I noticed that some TYPO3 extensions provide it as well. If one could explain a direct install via the CMS (TYPO3) for use with Direct Mail, I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The correct way

You need to do everything the PEAR installer does - but manually.

That is, read the `package.xml` file, note which files need to be extracted to which places (don't forget the `baseinstalldir`) and then extract the files.
After that you need to resolve all dependencies and install the dependent packages in the correct version as noted in the `package.xml` file.
Also do not forget to execute the replacement tasks as noted in the `package.xml` file.

## The fast way

Extract the tgz, delete `package.xml` and adjust your include path.

Then run fast and NEVER EVER ASK FOR HELP BECAUSE IT DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: Thanks. What's "don't forget the baseinstalldir" and "replacement tasks"?

Comment: See, you need to learn a lot until you can manually install pear packages as good as the pear installer.

Comment: Reason I was asking is that I wanted to avoid 'learning' pear. Otherwise I'd have been able to find the answer myself in the first place.

Comment: Use the "fast way". We once had a section "manually installing packages" in the pear manual, but removed it because it's too complex to do everything right.